# AngularJS HTTP.get Request not Working

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm tying to make a basic AngularJS app that pulls values I have from a .json file.  My code doesn't error when I run it, however it's not pulling the JSON values. I'm sure it's something simple and stupid that I'm missing, but I unfortunately can't figure it out.  Also, the {{1+2}} function I have inside the controller was there so I could test to make sure the application wasn't erroring out on me.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='phonebook'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phonebook.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="getPhonebook">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="contact in phonebook.entries">
                {{contact.name}} {{1+2}}
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/phonebook.js**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('phonebook', [ ]);



    app.controller("getPhonebook", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('js/phonebook.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.phonebook = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert('error');
        });
    });

})();
```

**js/phonebook.json**

```
{
    "entries" : [
        {
        "Name" : "Entry One",
        "Department" : "Department A",
        "Number" : [
            {
                "Name" : "Front Line",
                "Phone" : "1234567890",
                "Tieline" : "84543982"
            },
            {
                "Name" : "Back Line",
                "Phone" : "1243568790",
                "Tieline" : "58472989"
            }
        ],
        "Hours" :
            {
                "Sunday" : false, 
                "Monday" : "9AM – 6PM", 
                "Tuesday" : "9AM – 6PM", 
                "Wednesday" : "9AM – 6PM", 
                "Thursday" : "9AM – 6PM", 
                "Friday" : "9AM – 6PM", 
                "Saturday" : "9AM – 6PM"
            },
        "Description" : "…"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see here for demo http://plnkr.co/edit/MLTlizDbck1tzciWltOd?p=preview

in your HTML you've got `{{contact.name}}` instead `{{contact.Name}}`

HTML :

```
<body ng-controller="getPhonebook">

    <div ng-repeat="contact in phonebook.entries">
      {{contact.Name}}
       <ul><li ng-repeat="number in contact.Number">{{number.Name}} | {{number.Phone}}</li></ul>
    </div>


</body>
```

JS:
var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('getPhonebook', function($scope, $http) {



   $http.get('phonebook.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.phonebook = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          alert('error');
        });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something stupid and easy! And of course it's that I wasn't matching the case-sensitivity.